# Replace video width in MySQL database column

Tags: mysql, sql

My database has a table `content` with column `fulltext` where I embed videos like:

```
<iframe src="//example.com" width="600" height="518" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Now, the width has a lot of different sizes and in order to maximize and normalize the width of all videos, I'd like to change it to:

```
width="100%"
```

I tried the following query without success:

```
update `#__content` set `fulltext` = replace(`fulltext`,'width="600"','width="100%"')
```

But how to fix all sorts of different widths?

**Column fulltext `before` running the query:**

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">Neste âmbito, pretende-se essencialmente fomentar a compreensão do que é um ativo e um passivo, qual a diferença entre ambos, assim como o que é um gasto e um rendimento, em que demonstrações financeiras se enquadram e que informação se pode retirar das mesmas.</p>
```

**Column fulltext `after` running the query:**

```
100% style="text-align: justify;">Neste âmbito, pretende-se essencialmente fomentar a compreensão do que é um ativo e um passivo, qual a diferença entre ambos, assim como o que é um gasto e um rendimento, em que demonstrações financeiras se enquadram e que informação se pode retirar das mesmas.</p>
```

Comment: Do you want to replace all `'width="any number"`' to `''width="100%""` ?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here How you can use `substring_index` as

```
set @str = '<iframe src="//example.com" width="600" height="518" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
select 
replace(
   @str,replace(
     substring_index(
       substring_index(@str,'width=',-1
       ),' ',1
      ),'"',''
    ),'100%'
) as new_val;
```

Output would be

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| new_val                                                                                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| <iframe src="//example.com" width="100%" height="518" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So in the above query just replace @str with your column name and make it an update command.

The update command should be as

```
update `#__content` 
set `fulltext` = replace(
           `fulltext`,replace(
             substring_index(
               substring_index(`fulltext`,'width=',-1
               ),' ',1
              ),'"',''
            ),'100%'
        ) ;
```

**UPDATE**
For updating content inside iframe it needs some more chaining of `substring_index` as

```
set @str = '
<body>
<img src="/log.jpg" width="300">
<p style="width:200px;">hello</p>
<iframe src="//example.com" width="600" height="518" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';


select 
replace( 
  @str,
  replace(
    substring_index(
      substring_index(
        substring_index(
          substring_index(
             @str,'<iframe',-1
          ),
          '</iframe',1
        ),
        'width=',-1
      ), 
      ' ',1
    ),
    '"',''
   ),
   '100%'
) as new_val;

new_val: 
<body>
<img src="/log.jpg" width="300">
<p style="width:200px;">hello</p>
<iframe src="//example.com" width="100%" height="518" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

So the update query will be as

```
update `#__content` 
set `fulltext`=  
replace( 
  `fulltext`,
  replace(
    substring_index(
      substring_index(
        substring_index(
          substring_index(
             `fulltext`,'<iframe',-1
          ),
          '</iframe',1
        ),
        'width=',-1
      ), 
      ' ',1
    ),
    '"',''
   ),
   '100%'
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this code considering all the possible different widths? Note also that the src is different for each video.

Comment: @Abhik This is the code I used:  

set ‘fulltext’ = '<iframe src="//example.com" width="600" height="518" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
select 
replace(
   ‘fulltext’,replace(
     substring_index(
       substring_index(‘fulltext’,'width=',-1
       ),' ',1
      ),'"',''
    ),'100%'
) as new_val

Comment: Returned the error: #1193 - Unknown system variable 'â€˜fulltextâ€™'

Comment: It worked, but the thing is: it set the width to 100% for Everything (paragraphs, images, etc). In some cases, it messed up the HTML code. Is it possible to update ONLY the HTML inside an IFRAME?

Comment: Yes for that you need more chaining of `substring_index` check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the end result is the same.

Comment: End result is same ? In the example if you see I have a img tag and having a width which did not changed, could you copy one such column data into the question ?

Comment: Yep, I've just restored the site. On my edited question above you may see an example.

Comment: Just add a where condition as `where fulltext like  '%iframe src%'` , this will only pickup data having iframe in it.

Comment: [For more information about `substring_index`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/Mysql-pics/mysql-substring_index-positive.gif)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thanks but no go. That condition doesn't execute anything